# Django Celery and Django Debug Toolbar confilcts

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models, celery, djcelery

I have followed the celery documentation. yesterday i am able to update the Djcelery models in my Django admin. But today i am not able to update those models. I installed Django toolbar yesterday does it have any impact on functionality

Below is the Django admin screen shot with DDT included in settings.py

[image: Django admin SnapShot with Django Debug Toolbar]

Below is the screenshot of Django admin without DDT included in setting.py

[image: Django admin snapShot Without Django Debug Toolbar]

Installed Apps

INSTALLED_APPS = (

```
# django stuff
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',

# plugins
'precompressed', # https://github.com/jhmaddox/django-precompressed
'social.apps.django_app.default', # http://python-social-auth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration/django.html
'rest_framework', # https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework
'djcelery', # https://github.com/celery/django-celery
'celery_admin', # https://github.com/mattcaldwell/django-celery-admin-ext
'taggit', # https://github.com/alex/django-taggit
'south', # http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/
'storages', # http://django-storages.readthedocs.org/en/latest/
'redactor', # https://github.com/douglasmiranda/django-wysiwyg-redactor
'haystack', # http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/toc.html
'boomers.apps.djangoratings', #https://github.com/dcramer/django-ratings
'crowdsourcing',

# apps
'apps',
'apps.billing.chase',
'apps.billing.paypal',
'apps.billing.amazon',
'apps.config',
'apps.users',
'apps.learn',
'apps.community',
'api.careerbuilder',
'apps.care',
'apps.go',
'apps.play',
'apps.plan',
'apps.uplus',
'apps.billing',
'apps.googleanalytics',
)
```

and i have appended this INSTALLED_APPS += ('debug_toolbar',)

Comment: What's the error message when you try to make update?

Comment: the update option was not coming or disabled, i have commented out the django-toolbar dependency from my installed apps. Now am able to update the models in django admin

Comment: Please refer the image

Comment: Check how your `INSTALLED_APPS` looks like. Probably you missed `,` on one of the lines.

Comment: i have used this INSTALLED_APPS += ('debug_toolbar',) is that a problem? commented out the same for get it working

Comment: Can you post whole code of `INSTALLED_APPS` ?

Comment: updated the installed apps